# ¿El Ifelse tiene algún límite de comprobaciones?

Tags: r, condiciones, else

Tengo un `dataframe` de unas 200.000 filas con dos columnas de interés que se llaman **Crotal y clas**. Usando un `ifelse` quiero evaluar la condición de que cuando el **Crotal** sea ==  **XXXX**, me ponga 911, sino, 912. Debo hacer unos 200 cambios en total, pero un ejemplo de lo que hice es:

```
fd07d912$clas = with(fd07d912, ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000729643", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000729647", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000124962", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000124926", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000272780", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000388723", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000314655", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000392312", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000463118", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000314665", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000701390", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000124234", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB53375", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000314656", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000314587", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000270353", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB41239", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB40016", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB57433", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB57414", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000388722", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB43867", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB35997", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB56140", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB35984", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB32775", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000124230", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000124229", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB27635", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB52939", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB27026", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB43886", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB29216", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB40818", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB32789", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB43882", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB17167", "911", 
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB53018", "911",  
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB34375", "911",     
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000124226", "911",  
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB27058", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NAB26997", "911", 
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NA991189", "911",      
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NA980896", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NA980918", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NA981018", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NA962546", "911",   
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NA962588", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES1400NA090096", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000838064", "911",   
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140001106309", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000830080", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000830099", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000729633", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000729638", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140001106284", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140001106256", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000729641", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000719040", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000719050", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000719054", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000463143", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000463055", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000463047", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000463127", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000392289", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000392310", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000729636", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000392304", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000388710", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000314654", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000719034", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000388718", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000386544", "911",
                           ifelse(Crotal == "ES140000314636", "911", clas))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Al ejecutarlo, me sale:

> Error: contextstack overflow at line 50

He comprado paréntesis por paréntesis y todos los que abrí están correctamente cerrados. Lo único que se me ocurre es que haya un límite máximo de comparaciones posibles, porque por probar hice menos de 50 y funcionó. También me pregunto si existe alguna otra forma más rápida de hacer lo que necesito.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, efectivamente hay un límite y es de 50 "anidaciones" ([aquí](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/c48b62e3b4dd43d939e21f4af87e877151f1840b/src/main/gram.y#L1158) se puede ver en el código ese limite).

Fuente: [Is there a limit for the possible number of nested ifelse statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25063770/6836377)

#### ¿Como resolverlo?

1. Achicando la cantidad de anidaciones: Haces muchas comprobaciones por el `==` que apuntan al mismo código, podrías reducirlas si utilizas el `%in%`, por ehemplo:

   ```
   ifelse(Crotal %in% c("ES140000729647", "ES140000124962", ...), "911", "912")
   ```

   O también define un vector, con los 200 valores que mapean al `911`

   ```
    los_200_valores <- c("ES140000729647", "ES140000124962", ...)
    ifelse(Crotal %in%  los_200_valores, "911", "912")
   ```
2. Definir una tabla de conversión: En caso que tuvieras mucho casos más, puedes construir un `data.frame` de conversión:

   ```
    df_conversión = data.frame(x = c("ES140000729647", "ES140000124962", 'OTRO CODIGO'),
                       y = c("911", "911", "912"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    df <- data.frame(x = c('OTRO CODIGO', "ES140000729647", "ES140000124962"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    df$y <- df_conversión$y[match(df$x, df_conversión$x)]
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, como siempre tus explicaciones y ayuda son muy buenas. He usado la opción de definir un vector, que es la que me parece más sencilla

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de `case_when()` que comprueba varios valores dentro de una misma función. Por ejemplo:

```r
library(dplyr)

case_when(
  letters == "a" ~ "primera",
  letters == "j" ~ "décima",
  TRUE ~ letters
)

#  [1] "primera" "b"       "c"       "d"       "e"       "f"       "g"       "h"       "i"       "décima" 
# [11] "k"       "l"       "m"       "n"       "o"       "p"       "q"       "r"       "s"       "t"      
# [21] "u"       "v"       "w"       "x"       "y"       "z"
```

Si lo pasáramos a su versión de `ifelse()` se vería algo así:

```r
ifelse(letters == "a", "primera",
ifelse(letters == "j", "décima", letters))
```

Tan solo tendrías que ir agregando los test dentro de `case_when()`. A mayor cantidad de test se empezará a notar su ventaja sobre `ifelse()`.

Sin embargo, creo que tu problema podría ser solucionado de forma más general usando el operador `%in%` que te indica si los valores de un vector se encuentran presentes en un segundo vector de comparación.

```r
mis_letras <- c("a", "j")
ifelse(letters %in% mis_letras, "911", letters)

#  [1] "911" "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "f"   "g"   "h"   "i"   "911" "k"   "l"   "m"   "n"   "o"   "p"   "q"   "r"  
# [19] "s"   "t"   "u"   "v"   "w"   "x"   "y"   "z"
```

Claro, tendrías que ingresar los datos primero al vector con el que vas a compararlo, pero si estabas dispuesto a tipearlos todos no creo que sea un problema.